# Flutter : What are the available methods in MethodChannel?

Tags: flutter, platform

To access device APIs, you need method channel. let's create a Method Channel to get battery level,

```
var channel = MethodChannel('someName');
await channel.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel').then(
(lvl){
  print(lvl);
}
);
```

here I invoke a method called 'getBatteryLevel'. I came to know about this method from [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) page. But, how can I know there is a method called 'getBatteryLevel'.

what are the available methods in MethodChannel that I can Invoke?.

Thanks in advance

ANSWER---------
I found it,
methods declared in a file called MainActivity.java can only be used in invokeMethod(). So there is no predefined methods to invoke!

Comment: you cannot "list" available methods, you need to know them in advance

Comment: @psink how can i know them in advance?

Comment: they should be documented in `someName` channel documentation

Comment: @pskink How can i get that documentation?, thanks sir

Comment: what `MethodChannel` do you mean? where did you get it from?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/MethodChannel-class.html     It is a class  provided by flutter. I can't find any documentation online. Thanks a lot 

Comment: what `MethodChannel` do you use? what is passed as a string to `MethodChannel` constructor?

Comment: The String passed to the MethodChannel constructor is just a random channel name

Comment: Finally, I got it ! some method which i wanna use should be declared in a file called MainActivity.java. the getBetteryLevel is a function which should be declared ub MainActivity.java.